# Not able to display autocomplete for names

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

I want to show names as autocomplete in jsp page. I set a names list in action and want to see this as auto complete list for my names text box.
I am trying this with the help of following link
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

My code is

In jsp

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Names</span>
                <span class="ib"> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></span>
            </div>
<script>
                $('#name').autocomplete({
                    source: "test"
                });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In struts.xml

```
 <action name="test" class="iland.supplier.SupplierAction" method="test">
            <result  type="json"></result>
        </action>
```

in SupplierAction

```
public String test() {
        ArrayList<String> sss = new ArrayList<String>();
        sss.add("Manish");
        sss.add("Manoj");
        sss.add("Mohan");
        sss.add("Madhuri");
        sss.add("Mayank");
        sss.add("Mitesh");
        sss.add("Mitali");
        setNames(sss);
        for (String s : sss) {
            System.out.println(" " + s);
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

While clicking on name text box the list is printing on server concol.

Problem is I am not getting auto complete list in jsp page

Comment: Have you checked your browser console? (using tools like firebug). If you find anything post that too.

Comment: Then do that, It is processing via ajax. So it is possible to find either your client side or server side code which causes error.